# ZF3 - How to extends a controller from a framework in a vendor directory?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, composer-php, zend-framework3

I'm working with ZendFramework3 for a project. I have a module that works 
(for example : myProject/module/MyModule). Everything it's working but I would like to extends the controller which is in MyModule/src/Controller/CrudController. I mean, I have a simple module in my ZF3 project and I want the controller in this module to extends a Controller in a framework placed in myProject/vender/MyFramework/Mvc/Controller/

Problem is  Fatal error: Class 'MyFramework\Mvc\Controller\ExtendedController' not found in C:\wamp\www\myProject\module\MyModule\src\Controller\MyController.php on line 7

```
<?php
namespace MyModule\Controller;

use MyFramework\Mvc\Controller\ExtendedController;

class MyController extends ExtendedController
{
}
```

I don't know what am I supposed to do to find the Controller placed in a framework in the vendor directory.

If someone could help me on this, it would be a pleasure.

Currently, I based my code on what Zend does. For example, we could find this

```
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
```

I think the controller 'MyController' which extends the ExtendedController finds the right file but the controller is probably not load or something like that

Yours -)

EDIT : My problem has been resolved. The problem was the composer.json which needed to be updated.

I added this code in composer.json file :

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-0" : { "MyFramework\\": "vendor/MyFramework/{folder}/"},
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your module is not found by composer. Have a look at the composer.json file from zend-mvc, especially the autoload section. That's how composer knows how to register packages.

AFAIK you can't just place a package in the vendor dir. You need to create a complete [composer package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md) and add it to your composer.json require section.

What might be easier during development is placing your module inside the `./module/` dir. You can than edit your module and when it's ready you publish it via [packagist](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#publishing-to-packagist) or a [private composer repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md).
To get this working you need to add `MyFramework` to the autoload section of your project:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Application\\": "module/Application/src/",
        "MyFramework\\": "module/MyFramework/src/"
    }
},
```

Obviously, you need to update the autoloader with `composer dump-autoload` after changing the autoload section.

Comment: Actually, it's a good way to resolve my problem. But what about extern framework which does not belong to my project. As the zend framework. The zend-framework is in the vendor directory and we use classes from it. I want to do the same thing with my "MyFramework"

Comment: You need to do it the composer way. Create your own framework package, publish it somewhere (on packagist or your private repo) and then do `composer require MyFramework\MyFramework`. I already gave you the link on how to do it, but here it is again: https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md